# Kotlin - Type Erasure and Casting

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to understand how a `ClassCastException` can be thrown from code, where as far as I understand, the type being cast to has been erased.

### Example

```kotlin
class Foo<T : Any>(val key: String, val value: T) {
    override fun toString() = "$key: $value"
}

fun <T : Foo<*>> findByKey(items: Iterable<Foo<*>>, key: String): List<T> {
    return items.filter { it.key == key } as List<T>
}

fun main() {
    val items = listOf(
        Foo("a", "abc"), 
        Foo("a", 12345), 
        Foo("a", false)
    )
    
    val filtered = findByKey<Foo<String>>(items, "a")
    println(filtered)
    
    val values = filtered.map { it.value }
    println(values)
}
```

### Output

> [a: abc, b: 12345, c: false]
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

There are a couple of sore thumbs sticking out here:

- Type `T` in `findByKey` is not `reified`, therefore erased.
- `findByKey` accepts `Iterable<Foo<*>` rather than `Iterable<T>` (deliberately).
- There's an unchecked cast to `List<T>`.

What I find interesting is that:

- Calling `findByKey<Foo<String>>(items, "a")` doesn't throw `ClassCastException`.
- In the JVM I'd expect this call to be `findByKey(items, "a")` as `<Foo<String>>` is erased.
- Calling `filtered.map { it.value }` throws a `ClassCastException`.

I'm not looking for a solution to how to get this code working; I already know that. Rather, I'm curious to know why calling `map` throws a `ClassCastException` for a type that I believe to be erased?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java generics type erasure: when and what happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Answer (score 1):

The type isn’t yet erased at compile time. The compiler knows you have cast to `List<Foo>`, and has to cast the individual items to Foo to be able to get their `value` property in `map`. At runtime, the source type is not known, but the destination type needed to call its `value` property *is* known. So this cast is hard coded at compile time, before any erasure.

The exception message tells you the source type of the individual item that produced the cast error. The coded type of your List is unknown, but individual objects can be inspected to determine their type.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the type information for `String` from inside the findByKey function?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. But you can change the parameter type of `items` to `Iterable<T>` and then you don't have to cast it to `List<T>` at all.

Comment: There is a reason it’s `Iterable<Foo<*>>`, because it represents a data source outside of Kotlin. What I’m asking is, if the compiler knows at some point that the result has been cast, and what it’s been cast to, can you get that type information from anywhere (without reifying the type)?

Comment: You can retrieve the class of a specific object with `::class` and you can check if its type matches something with `is`. What you cannot retrieve at runtime is generic types. So you can loop through a `List<*>` or `List<Any>` and use `is` checks on each individual item to safely cast them. But you can never find out what the generic type of the whole List is.

Answer (score 0):

If you decompile your code, you will see that `map` function is translated into the following code:

```
Iterable $this$map$iv = (Iterable)filtered;
Collection destination$iv$iv = (Collection)(new ArrayList(CollectionsKt.collectionSizeOrDefault($this$map$iv, 10)));
Iterator var8 = $this$map$iv.iterator();
while(var8.hasNext()) {
   Object item$iv$iv = var8.next();
   Foo it = (Foo)item$iv$iv;
   String var13 = (String)it.getValue();
   destination$iv$iv.add(var13);
}
List values = (List)destination$iv$iv;
```

And this line `String var13 = (String)it.getValue();` throws a `ClassCastException`

Comment: So in actual fact, `String` is not erased? Is there a way to obtain this information from Kotlin?